# is there a way to monitor DNS requests that come through the local windows DNS cache?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, cache, internal-dns

is there a way to monitor DNS requests that come through the local windows DNS cache?

i.e. to see say one line entry for each request, and that line entry would include the detail of whether it was serviced locally, or whether it had to go outside the PC to the next DNS server to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ipconfig /displaydns
```